# onActivityResult() is not called after I run finish in the child activity

Tags: android

I'm attempting to pass data between two activities with startActivityForResult(). Here is my code:

```
//Within an onOptionsItemSelected method
//..
intent.setClass(this, FileManager.class);
startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
//..
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent){
    Log.w("result Recieved", "request code: " + requestCode + ", result code: " + resultCode);
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
    if (requestCode == 0 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
        extras = intent.getExtras();
        if(extras != null){
            Log.w("result Recieved", "extras non null\n" + extras.toString());
            root = new File(extras.getString("SelectedDir"));
            fileName = extras.getString("SelectedFile");
            loadFile(root, fileName);
        }
    }
}
```

In the FileManager I have:

```
//..
Intent i = new Intent();
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("selectedFile", file.getName());
bundle.putString("selectedDir", file.getPath());
i.putExtras(bundle);
setResult(RESULT_OK, i);
Log.d("Finishing status:", "Finishing");
finish();
//..
```

It doesn't receive a result until I re-open the activity at which point FileManager is forced to close. This causes the request and result code to be 0, indicating failure. The FileManager class works by displaying a list of files, when one is selected an alert dialog appears for confirmation and in the listener for yes input I call the method detailed above. How do I make it return a result following the call to finish?

EDIT:

I believe the problem is a listener or something continuing to run after finish is called. I'm not sure what though. I've written a test application that switches between two activities with buttons and it works, I have basically the same code as this project without all the extra methods.

EDIT2:
  I commented out basically everything in the FileManager class and it still doesn't return the result right. So, it must be a problem with the activity that starts it.

EDIT3:
  There error was in some old code I forgot to delete, before the switch case statement I put the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag on the intent.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with what you have there.  What do you mean "until I re-open the activity?"  Presumably when you finish FileManager it immediately goes back to the previous activity?  Do you have any special flags on the Activities in your manifest?  What do you have after startActivityForResult()?

Comment: Yes, after I call finish it goes back to the parent. after startActivityForResult() it breaks from a switch statement and runs `return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);` then it will do nothing until onActivityResult(){ is called or the user does something. The parent method is not finished. In the manifest I just have the name and the label entered for both activities except the parent has no title bar and is landscape. I reopen the activity after finish is called through selecting it's option again on the pop-out menu.

Comment: So you are saying you 1. startActivityForResult() from Activity1 2. finish Activity2, send back a result.  3. Activity1 gets restarted, but onActivityResult is not called. 4. You restart Activity2, and it crashes?  I don't really believe that 3 is happening... Do you have any special flags on the Activities in your manifest? What is the stacktrace from the force close?

Comment: There is no force close Activity A does not receive the data from Activity B.

Answer (score 0):

I had unnecessary flags on the intent. Also I need to remember to remove old code I used for testing.

Comment: Could you add what unnecessary flag you had?